# Trouble with simple hit counter in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm cobbling together a very simple PHP script, but I can't get it to work. I'm connecting to the SQL database, but it's not retrieving the value I want. I just have a single entry in a single table in a single database. I want to retrieve that value, then add one to it.

```
    <?php 
        $dbhost = 'localhost'; 
        $dbuser = 'root'; 
        $dbpass = 'root'; 
        $dbname = 'test'; 
        $dbtable = 'counter'; 

        //------ DATABASE CONNECTION --------// 
        mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) 
        or die ("Unable to connect to database"); 

        mysql_select_db($dbname) 
        or die ("Unable to select database"); 

        $test = "SELECT FIRST('count') FROM $dbtable";

    ?> 

    This button has been clicked <?php echo $test; ?> times.
```

EDIT: Found a solution with the aid of angelo

```
    <?php 
    //parameters to set
    $dbhost = 'localhost'; 
    $dbuser = 'root'; 
    $dbpass = 'root'; 
    $dbname = 'test'; 
    $dbtable = 'counter'; 
    $dbcolumn = 'count';
    //end of list of parameters to set
    $connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    if(!$connect){die("Connection error");}
    $test = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT ".$dbcolumn." FROM ".$dbtable);
    $assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test);
    $num = $assoc[$dbcolumn];


?> 

This button has been clicked <?php echo $num; ?> times.

<?php

    $plus = $num+1;
    //mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ".$dbtable."('".$dbcolumn."') VALUES ('".$plus."')");
    mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE FROM counter WHERE count = $num");
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO counter (count) VALUES ($plus)");

?>
```

Comment: Your query has nothing to do with what you describe.

Comment: You're treating your column as a value.

Comment: Plus, `FIRST` isn't an aggregate function. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why your code is not working

You're not launching your query

### Warning

You're using mysql_ functions, which are deprecated. You should use mysqli_ instead.

### Solution

Use this code:

```
 <?php 
        //parameters to set
        $dbhost = 'localhost'; 
        $dbuser = 'root'; 
        $dbpass = 'root'; 
        $dbname = 'test'; 
        $dbtable = 'counter'; 
        $dbcolumn = 'col';
        //end of list of parameters to set
        $connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
        if(!$connect){die("Connection error");}
        $test = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT ".$dbcolumn." FROM ".$dbtable);
        $assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test);
        $num = $assoc[$dbcolumn];
        ?> 

    This button has been clicked <?php echo $num; ?> times.
```

Please note that this code only *shows* the number of clicks.
To add one to this value, append the following code to the previous one:

```
<?php
$plus = $num+1;
$query = "UPDATE ".$dbtable." SET ".$dbcolumn."='".$plus."'";
mysqli_query($connect,$query);
?>
```

Comment: This works other than the part meant to increment the value

Comment: Wooops, that's my fault. I edited my answer. Let me now if it works now :)

Comment: Hmm I might be doing something wrong but it's still not workin this way for me

Comment: Again my fault. I tested my code and found two errors. Sorry, I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: Now it should work (I tested this version), let me now if it does :)